# Rails: purpose of downloading gems locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

Generally, if I need a gem, I put it in the Gemfile and bundle install. However, I don't understand if there is a benefit to downloading the gems locally first with `gem install _____`. Is there any benefit to this? Does `bundle install` no longer have to connect to the net in that situation?

Comment: ohk..First you need to understand how blunder works ..if you have some time then read this http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/9/24/how-does-bundler-bundle

Answer (score 0):

Bundler installs the gems located in your Gemfile locally the same as if you ran gem install for each of those gems.

Answer (score 0):

Gem install needed for gems that can be used outside of bundler applications. For example [request-log-analyzer](https://github.com/wvanbergen/request-log-analyzer) need to be installed outside of any apps for be available in command line.

Answer (score 0):

I myself use `gem install _______` then i use `bundle install --local` which doesn't require internet connection if the gem is found locally but will return an error if the gem was not found locally...

I find this method faster in downloading and installing gems, plus if the gems are found locally then i have also the benefit of altering the gemfile and install the gems without having internet connection.